# How to overwrite files over FTP using command?

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, ftp-client

I have written such a shell script which uploads files over ftp to my deployment server . This script working perfectly if you want full-deployment i.e entire project in one go . but problem is when i change specific file on local machine and now i want it to overwrite existing same file on server using ftp it's not overwriting.

```
MKDIR=`for directory in $FOLDERS; do echo "mkd \"${directory}\""; done`
DELETE=`for file in $DFILES; do echo "delete \"${file}\""; done`
ATTACH=`for file in $FILES; do echo "put \"${file}\""; done`


IFS=$ORIGIFS
# Send updates to server
    ftp -nv <<EOF
    open $FTPHOST
    user $FTPUSER $FTPPASS
    binary
    cd $FTPDIR
    $MKDIR
    $ATTACH
    quit
 EOF
```

Where: FOLDERS:contains directories to create, DELETE is string which has deleted files list , ATTACH has list of files that has been modified and needs to be overwritten on server that are exist.

After that when i run it second time after modification in existing files  :

```
       local: ./testproject/trunk/test.php ./svnupdate.txt remote: ./testproject/trunk/test.php ./svnupdate.txt
       local: ./testproject/trunk/test.php ./svnupdate.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The file name to copy/delete/create looks like two file names joined.

Comment: How to separate this files ? This files names are stored in FILES variable in single line string.

Comment: Please, post the script lines where the FILES variable is filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer .

Problem statement in my script :

```
ATTACH=`for file in $FILES; do echo "put \"${file}\""; done`
```

where i create list of files to upload.But this code concatenate each file names as told by @Jdamian.
@Jdamian thanks for point out my mistake.

Solution:

```
ATTACH=`for file in $FILES
do
    echo "put $file"
done`
```